# FTP file download using Delphi IdFTP

Tags: ftp, delphi-xe

I am new to delphi, I need to write an ftp client program that will go through a text file with list of ftp addresses, and download the subfolders from an ftp site .
I have successfully hooked to the server but got stuck on the download part. can someone please help me with the codes to insert in the download procedure

```
 procedure TCleint.btnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    try
       if not IdFTP.Connected then
       begin
           IdFTP.Host := 'ftp server';
           IdFTP.Username := 'anonymous';
           IdFTP.Password := 'emailaddress';
           IdFTP.Port := 21;
           IdFTP.Connect;

           IdFTP.List(listaDirectory.Items, '', false);

           btnConnect.Enabled := False;
           btnDisconnect.Enabled := True;
           btnDownload.Enabled := True;

       end;
    except
         on E:Exception do
         begin
             MessageDlg('connection error!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
             btnConnect.Enabled := true;
             btnDisconnect.Enabled := false;
             btnDownload.Enabled := false;
         end;
    end;
end;

procedure TCleint.btnDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    try
       if IdFTP.Connected then
       begin
           IdFTP.Disconnect;

           listaDirectory.Clear;
           btnConnect.Enabled := True;
           btnDisconnect.Enabled := False;
           btnDownload.Enabled := False;
       end;
    except
        on E:Exception do
        begin
          MessageDlg('connection error!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
          btnConnect.Enabled := false;
          btnDisconnect.Enabled := true;
          btnDownload.Enabled := true;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TCleint.btnDownloadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

After calling `List()`, you need to loop through the entries of the `DirectoryListing` property.  That will tell you which items are files and which are subfolders.  You can then `Get()` the files and (recursively) `ChangeDir()`/`List()` the subfolders.